# Missing cxf jar: Please select the cxf home directory

Tags: java, eclipse, cxf

I am learning creating a SOAP web service in Eclipse Luna. I downloaded the binary version CXF and extracted it. Now, Eclipse gives me the above error when I try to add the CXF runtime. I checked the extracted folder but there is no CXF jar file as such. I Googled it but could not find it.

Do I have to download only a specific version that would be compatible with **LUNA**.
Moreover, I was also able to install 2 out of 3 Eclipse plugins (Checkstyle, PMD). I did not get the 3rd one ( Subversion plugin).

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On Eclipse, Go to Windows menu --> Preferences. Search for `CXF`  and you'll see a `CVF 2.x Preferences`. On `CXF Runtime` tab, click the add button and search for the installation of the CXF folder (this should come by unzipping the latest CXF release found on the [download](http://cxf.apache.org/download.html) page). Select the **root** folder of the CXF library and let Eclipse find the version and type. Once done, click `Finish`.

Comment: I am exactly following the same thing. As soon as I browse to the path of CXF folder, it gives me this error:  **Missing CXF jar. Please select the CXF home directory**. @Buhake

Comment: The home directory is the directory where the `bin` folder is located and the cxf jar must exist in the `lib` folder. If both folder exists then you are at the home directory.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response @Buhake. It finally works, man!  This time i chose the path...._C:\Users\coolron619\Apache Tomcat\apache-cxf-3.0.1\apache-cxf-3.0.1_...Earlier, I was _C:\Users\coolron619\Apache Tomcat\apache-cxf-3.0.1_......I dont know why it didn't work. However, thanks a lot for the immediate help.