# Trying to add CXF3.1.11 to eclipse Web Service runtime but getting "Missing CXF jar: please select the CXF Home Directory"

Tags: web-services, cxf

Trying to add CXF3.1.11 to eclipse Web Service runtime but getting

> Missing CXF jar: please select the CXF Home Directory.

Tried adding extra "apache-cxf-3.1.11-src" to the path of "C:\Program Files\Apache\apache-cxf-3.1.11-src\" as suggested in one of the posts but did not work. Also notice that my bin folder is located in "C:\Program Files\Apache\apache-cxf-3.1.11-src\distribution\src\main\release" but bin does not has any jar instead lib folder has a file named WHICH_JARS

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is actually looking for a specific jar file and is unable to find it.  You appear to have downloaded the CXF source code and not the binary distribution [located here (well it's 2.X)](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/cxf/3.2.0/apache-cxf-3.2.0.zip) but thats likely still not going to help you much as apparently Eclipse seems to be looking for a possibly old CXF 2.X version (it does show Window->Preferences->Web Services->CXF 2.x Preferences) as I added the binary version of apache-cxf-3.1.6 and it found the run time but couldnt locate the jar though they are there.  I then tried the linked binary version above, again the runtime is found but I still the error "Missing CXF jar: please select the CXF Home Directory."

So in short (well long) and to answer your question though I dont believe it will help - you'd need to build the source code you downloaded.  Sorry I cant be of more help.  These people had a similar problem [Missing cxf jar: Please select the cxf home directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25118750/missing-cxf-jar-please-select-the-cxf-home-directory) and were able to solve it but it appears somethings changed in the latest versions of eclipse or possibly apache?